# Is it possible to display a figure by referencing it after it was displayed earlier on in the document?

Tags: graphics, shortcut

For example, in Page 1 my tex file I write

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \begin{center}
        \includegraphics[scale=0.6]{Figure_1}
    \end{center}
    \caption{Figure 1}
    \label{fig:Figure1}
\end{figure}
```

But on page 10, I want to display the figure again, do I still need to do

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \begin{center}
        \includegraphics[scale=0.6]{Figure_1}
    \end{center}
    \caption{Figure 1}
    \label{fig:Figure1}
\end{figure}
```

or is there some short cut like \display{Figure_1} or something that I can just call since Latex already knows what Figure_1 is referencing?

Comment: Is the problem solved, or are you looking for a different/better solution to you needs?

Comment: @runartrollet I will leave the question open for another day to see if everyone agrees on the solution. I posted it over the weekend so maybe some people have not seen this post yet and has some other perspectives on this problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Savebox

You could use `\savebox`, but you need to add caption, labels, and `\begin{figure}`/`\end{figure}` each time you want to to that. This is more flexible, but needs a bit more work everytime you need to add an image. Hopefully, you don't need to include the same image too many times.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newsavebox{\exampleFigure}
\savebox{\exampleFigure}{%
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-a}%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[hbt]
  \centering
  \usebox{\exampleFigure}
  \caption{Example image}
\end{figure}

Some text\ldots

\begin{figure}[hbt]
  \centering
  \usebox{\exampleFigure}
  \caption{Example image}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

### Newcommand

You could alternatively use a `\newcommand`, but then you would have to make sure you only reference it one, or create a new label for it every time. Some editors keeps track of all your labels, and doing it this way will not enable the editor to keep track of them.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\exampleFigure}[1]{%
\begin{figure}[hbt]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-a}
  \caption{Example image}
  \label{#1}
\end{figure}%
}
\begin{document}
\exampleFigure{fig:exampleFigureFirst}

Some text\ldots

\exampleFigure{fig:exampleFigureSecond}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: in the first one you need `%` at ends of lines in the `\savebox` and remove the `\centering` (as it does nothing in horizontal mode)` then use `\centering before the `\usebox`

Comment: Why do you define `\examplefigure` to insert a paragraph break in the flow of text? That means if you try to insert the figure mid-paragraph, you'll get an unexpected paragraph break as a result. If the figure floats elsewhere, this is very unlikely to be desirable. Also, here, you probably do want `\centering` for the `figure`.

Comment: @cfr Oh, my bad. Just some mistakes of editing. You are right. I have corrected it now.